# Clients couldn't query DNS server listening on router interface's secondary IP

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, dnsmasq, iproute2

I have a router where its interface has two IPs

```
$ ip addr

br-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether <MA> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.1/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global br-lan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.3.2/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global secondary br-lan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Dnsmasq is listening on both IPs, which I can confirm by querying to either `192.168.3.1` and `192.168.3.2` on the router, and I would get answers back.

However, my client (192.168.3.100) connected to the router with a wire, can query only `192.168.3.1` and get answers back. When querying to `192.168.3.2`, the router returns "port unreachable" ICMP error, yet it's able to ping `192.168.3.2` and get responses.

What might be the reason for ICMP error?

Comment: To be sure of how is running `dnsmasq`, can you provide the full options on its command line (eg with `ps -f -p $(pgrep dnsmasq)`) or from its configuration? The way it can use its interface options could matter. Also can you provide the result of `ss -anp sport == 53`?

Comment: Anyway, OP didn't give updates, but I'm quite sure in this case dnsmasq is bound to INADDR_ANY for UDP and doesn't use the IP_PKTINFO option to handle correct UDP replies for a multi-homed server (ok just multi-addresses).